# How implement field with JsonNode type in DTO model

Tags: java, jackson

So I have json file like:

```
{ "id" : 1,
   "includingJson" : {"foo" : "bar"}
}
```

And I have some DTO like:

```
...
public class SubscriptionDTO extends AbstractDTO{
  private Long id;
  private JsonNode includingJson;
```

But after I try convert JSON to POJO, by code

```
public static <T> T jsonStringToDto(Class<?> dtoClass, String jsonContent) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  try {
    return (T) mapper.readValue(jsonContent, dtoClass);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    log.error(e);
  }
  return (T) new Object();
}
```

I've got error message `Can not construct instance of org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information`
So the main problem - how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you imported wrong JsonNode, which is older. Proper class to use is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`, and it works. Tested it with Jackson 2.8. Also to ensure proper work it's best if DTO classes have getters, setters, and no-arg constructors. So, update the version.

Comment: Yes, It has started to work after I had upgraded my Jakson version to 2.9.8. Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your DTO to look like this:

```
public class SubscriptionDTO extends AbstractDTO{
  private Long id;
  private InnerDTO includingJson;

  //..getters, setters
}
```

And you InnerDTO class:

```
public class InnerDTO extends AbstractDTO{
  private String foo;

  //..getters, setters
}
```

Comment: It's looking like workaround solution, It could work, but I want more generic solution. Anyway thank you for this trick